# graphql mutation using input object

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-java

I'm using graphql apollo client for Android. I'm able to pass data using mutation for a single fields without any issue. While using input object in mutation the error **cannot read property of email undefined** occurred. But same graphql working while running in the browser.

Graphql mutation

```
mutation signup($SignupInput:SignupInput) {
    signup(data: $SignupInput) {
        result{token,firstName,lastName,profileImage}
   }
}
```

Input

```
    {"SignupInput": {"firstName": "John","lastName": "Peter","email": "john@gmail.com"
,"password": "123123"}}
```

Java Code for API call

```
final SignupInput signupInput=SignupInput.builder()
                .firstName(edtSignUpName.getText().toString())
                .lastName(edtSignUpLastName.getText().toString())
                .email(actvSignUpEmail.getText().toString())
                .password(edtSignUpPassword.getText().toString())
                .profileImage("dasfasdfasdf.png").build();


        final SignupMutation signupMutation = SignupMutation.builder()
                .signupInput(signupInput)
                .build();
        signupCall = appController.apolloClient()
                .mutate(signupMutation);
        signupCall.enqueue(dataCallback);
```

Comment: Is this a Java error? Can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: I changed the $SignupInput to $signupInput, In android or java user should use CamelCase. That is an issue in mutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mutation signup($SignupInput:SignupInput)
{
    signup(data: $SignupInput) {
        result{token,firstName,lastName,profileImage}
   }
}
```

I changed the **$SignupInput to $signupInput**, In android or java user should use **CamelCase**. That is an issue in mutation